# State pattern using methods

Tags: c#, func, state-machine

I'm trying to implement a simple state machine based on a modified version of the state pattern using methods as states instead of classes, something like this:

```
private Action<Input> currentState;
private void NextState(Input i) {
    currentState(i);
}

private void State1(Input i) {
    if( i ... )
        currentState = State1;
    else
        currentState = State2;
}

private void State2(Input i) {
    if( i ... )
        currentState = State1;
    else
        currentState = State2;  
}
```

But it would be more elegant if I could do:

```
private void NextState(Input i) {
    currentState = currentState(i);
}

private Func<xxx> State1() {
    if( i ... )
        return State1;
    else
        return State2;
}
```

But I don't know how to write this `Func`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe I'm not familiar with what you're doing, but typically state machines are defined by a single state variable. This is often best described by an `enum` of the states.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use functions which return `void`, try using [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) instead.

```
private Action State1() {
    if( ... )
        return State1Inner;
    else
        return State2Inner;
}
```

If you want to use a function which returns a function with it's own signature, you have to define a custom delegate type first. Here's a generic version:

```
public delegate State<T> State<T>(T input);

private State<int> State1(int input) {
    if( ... )
        return State1;
    else
        return State2;
}
```

This will help you avoid having inner state functions.

Comment: +1. Also for traditional FSM it should be `Action<TInput>` as transitions should be happening based on some sort of input value.

Comment: I want it to be simple, without inner states, that is, one state should be able to return itself or other states (based on some TInput, which I didn't write in my example). So states don't return void, the question is I don't know what it returns.

Comment: @Roberto then you would need to define a custom delegate. See my updated answer

Comment: @p.s.w.g Thank you. I was confused about writing a delegate in which the type is the method itself. I still don't understand why it can't be `public delegate State<int> State<int>(int input);`

Comment: @Roberto it can be just `public delegate State State(int input)` but then it wouldn't be generic.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [this article](http://shadowcoding.blogspot.com/2009/01/yield-and-c-state-machine.html), which discusses the use of the yield statement for doing state machines. This is [commonly done](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) in, for example, [in the Unity3d game engine](http://www.playmedusa.com/blog/2010/12/15/simple-fsm-like-structure-with-coroutines-in-c-unity3d/). (another discussion [here](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/07/07/unity3d-coroutines-in-detail/))

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use methods as states and kind of refer to them "generically", you want function pointers. I'm not familiar with the syntax in c# but in c++ you can pass a pointer to a function, and call that function using its pointer. Essentally this means using a function as a paramater/variable - an action that will be used, but is unknown before runtime.

Look into function pointers, I think that will get you where you need to be,  although I'm curious about the nature of what you are doing here exactly.

if you ARE using c#, it uses something called function delegates rather than pointers. read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx