# how to correctly extend classes for character

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine, state-machine, extending

I am working on a 2d game in unity3d (c#) with the character controlled by the arrow keys and with 2 action buttons.

My problem is simple, I can solve it, but the solution seems bit dirty to me. I am using a very simple state machine, the hero is moving in horizontal or vertical way (floor and ladder)

my current state extending is:

> HeroState -> HeroStateStatic -> HeroStateMovement

Then I extend static or movement to final states:

> HeroStateMovement -> HeroStateRunning or HeroStateStatic ->
>   HeroStateLookUp

however I am always calling a huge external function (in Hero class) which decides what to do next and then switch the state

I believe I should have this reasoning within the state itself but states at ladder has different set of checks and possible choices then states at floor and I don't know how to rework those classes to have all necessary code written just one (that's why now is in hero and not in the states) ... is there anything like cross-extending technique?

(I know how to use abstract classes and interfaces but it probably does not solve my trouble)

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can really be solved with a state machine, but since you have a huge class deciding what to do, it seems that you are having trouble implementing the [state pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).

This [blog post](http://paulgestwicki.blogspot.co.nz/2011/06/state-design-pattern-in-unity-with-c.html) has a good explanation about implementing the state pattern in an Unity application, and you can easily google for more resources.

Once I wanted to create a simple state machine that used methods as states, just for convenience (because the pattern use classes as state). One could use this as a way to have state machines inside states (which also can be achieved with the regular state pattern), so if you want to know about this you can read [my stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607074/state-pattern-using-methods).

Comment: thx for answer - the huge decision method is huge, because it's shared by all states and my problem is, that many states share this decision solving - for example, WalkState RunState and JumpState have almost the same decision solving - what i'd need is multiple inheritance, which does not work in c# and i am looking for some other solution in c#

Comment: I don't fully understand. You said the method is huge because it solves for many states. Thus, it's not a generic decision because it has to solve the particularities of the many states. Than why instead of having a huge method you can't a smaller decision method inside each state? If those 3 states have almost the same solving method than it could inherit from one base class, so why would you need multiple inheritance?

Comment: sry my english is not quite native :D it solves decision in many states for example: after Run or Walk movement it it asks if hero wants to Run or Walk or Jump or Stay or Turn but if you are at the end of the room it knows you cant move forward so you can Turn only, there are states which are moving you from floor to ladder and then it asks what you can and want to do at ladder, i have 2 deciding functions DecideFloor, DecideLadder, however you can be in situations on floor, like LookUp, LookDown states which you cant leave by running for example

Comment: these all look like many small states for me, which could be implemented with the regular state machine pattern.

Comment: yes i will do it that way, each animation state (i am using mecanim) will have it's equivalent in my code and that will be bullet proof ... thanks guys!!!!

Comment: actually the right answer is the one about many small states, which i am already using and i wanted to somehow make them not to use one huge method for reasoning, so right now i am trying to do it, but i see it's not possible, because i have same code in many states ... the way (by my opinion) could be solved with multiple inheritance or external methods or substates - all has pros and all has cons - MANY THANKS ROBERTO!